# UNC path in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created a set of ASP pages which receive HTTP requests. Some of these requests pull data from a database, and few of them open text files to get info.  My path to these text files are pretty straight-forward on my web server, and I refer to these in my `web.config` as below in the `appSettings` node.

```
<add key="MasterPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VecoXtra\" />
```

However, my client (who is going to use this) has set up my scripts on their server but wants to use a UNC path to these files, and the process stops when changing it to:

```
<add key="MasterPath" value="\\10.10.6.2\euro$\INETPUB\VeXtra\StaticFiles\" />
```

I read somewhere to double up the slashes, but to no avail, as I think there are some permissions issues here.  I tried identity in my config and adding my windows administrator login to the application pool but nothing allows me to access these files.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, the error is Access to the path '\\10.10.6.2\euro$\INETPUB\VeXtra\StaticFiles\PropertyList.txt' is denied.

Comment: I also changed the path to something that does NOT exist and I get the same message with the wrong path..

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Applcation Pool AND the setting to load profile to true and it kicked into gear.. thanks for letting me talk it through :)